# BlueprintJS not rendering components

Tags: blueprintjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/blueprint-sandbox-f6ekm

Some components with BlueprintJS are not working. 
I'm following the docs but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify more details? Your sandbox example is rendering fine.

I use Blueprint for building desktop apps, everything works fine ([except some bugs](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues)) and I just love this UI toolkit.

If you want to see how Switch component works convert it a class component and add the switch position into the state.

```
return (
  <div>
    <Switch
      label={this.state.enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"}
      checked={this.state.enabled}
      onChange={() => this.setState({ enabled: !this.state.enabled})}
    />
  </div>
);
```

See your example extended https://codesandbox.io/s/blueprint-sandbox-biq69

**EDIT**
Also `onChange` passes ChangeEvent as the first argument.

```
<Switch onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => this.yourHandler(event)}/>
```

In `yourHandler` you can get the state of the switch like this: `event.target.checked`